# How to make something like this?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm not sure if I'm correct in wording it "modal sprite-kit scene" but what I'm trying to do is have a smaller sized scene appear over a scene when the game is complete. Attached is a screenshot to show what I mean: [image]

The screenshot is from Flappy Bird where when the player dies, the small game-over scene pops up almost like a modal effect, and displays the user's final results. I was wondering how to go about creating this.

I tried calling this when the game was done:

```
[self.player runAction:death completion:^{
        [self removeAllActions];
        GameOverNode *gameOverNode = [[GameOverNode alloc] initWithScore:self.size];
        gameOverNode.gameScene = self;
        gameOverNode.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2, -150);
        [self addChild:gameOverNode];
        [gameOverNode runAction:[SKAction moveToY:self.scene.size.height/2 duration:0.6]];
```

And this was the code for the gameOverNode in the gameOverScene.m's file:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

            self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.zPosition = 20;
            SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(280*DoubleIfIpad, 300*DoubleIfIpad)];
            bg.alpha = 0.55;
```

But the node only shows up in the bottom left hand corner of the screen, as opposed to in the middle like I want it too.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I make the small gameover node pop up and sit in the middle of the scene.**

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of you buggy modal window? If you see it in the bottom left corner than your SKAction moveToY is not working or you haven't shown us whole code.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. According to Apple Docs and multiple StackOverflow posts you cannot be running two SKScene's at the same time. To recreate the effect you want, you can create an `SKShapeNode` with border and line color similar to those you want, and place objects like score inside, or you can create an image for the screen that pops up and just add `SKLabelNode`s to the scene that show the high score and current score. I'm attaching a picture of how I created an end "view" for my app, Average Guy.

[image: end screen]

I made the popup screen using an SKShapeNode like this:

```
SKShapeNode *optionsMenu = [SKShapeNode node];

CGRect    tempRect = CGRectMake(SELF_WIDTH/2, SELF_HEIGHT/2, SELF_WIDTH-20, (finalScoreLabel.position.y+(finalScoreLabel.frame.size.height/2)) - (mainMenuButton.position.y-(mainMenuButton.frame.size.height/2)) + 20);
CGPathRef tempPath = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(tempRect.origin.x - tempRect.size.width/2, tempRect.origin.y - tempRect.size.height/2, tempRect.size.width, tempRect.size.height), 5, 5, Nil);

optionsMenu.path        = tempPath;
optionsMenu.fillColor   = [SKColor grayColor];
optionsMenu.strokeColor = [SKColor blueColor];
optionsMenu.zPosition   = 30;
optionsMenu.glowWidth   = 2.0f;

CGPathRelease(tempPath);
```

Of course, don't mind the hectic CGRect implementation, I wanted to make everything relative to fit all of the screen sizes so I didn't hardcode any of the positions. As for adding the score and the buttons, I did this:

```
SKLabelNode *restartButton = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"00 Starmap Truetype"];
restartButton.text         = @"Play Again";
restartButton.zPosition    = 31;
restartButton.fontColor    = [SKColor blueColor];
restartButton.fontSize     = 30;
restartButton.position     = CGPointMake(HALF_WIDTH, HALF_HEIGHT-50);
restartButton.name         = @"restart_button";

SKLabelNode *restartButtonShadow = restartButton.copy;
restartButtonShadow.position = CGPointMake(restartButton.position.x+1, restartButton.position.y-1);
restartButtonShadow.color = [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:.5 alpha:.1];

SKLabelNode *mainMenuButton = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"00 Starmap Truetype"];
mainMenuButton.text         = @"Main Menu";
mainMenuButton.zPosition    = 31;
mainMenuButton.fontColor    = [SKColor blueColor];
mainMenuButton.fontSize     = 30;
mainMenuButton.position     = CGPointMake(HALF_WIDTH, HALF_HEIGHT - 85);
mainMenuButton.name         = @"main_menu_button";
```